# Regexp not matching digits in "1 1" JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

This is probably a silly mistake, but I can't figure out why this isn't working

```
var patt = new RegExp("\s[A-Za-z0-9]");
var filtering = patt.test("1 1");
console.log(filtering);
```

I get false from `filtering`, but from my understanding `filtering` should be true

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
var patt = new RegExp("\s[A-Za-z0-9]");
```

… creates the following regular expression:

```
/s[A-Za-z0-9]/
```

Note that there's no backslash (`\`) before the `s`, because a backslash in a string expression has to be escaped (with another backslash).

Fix that, and you'll get `true` as expected:

```js
var patt = new RegExp("\\s[A-Za-z0-9]");
var filtering = patt.test("1 1");
console.log(filtering);
```